# api key not found in swiftUI

Tags: api, urlsession, jsondecoder, codingkey

While extracting details from the api I'm receiving error as "**keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "propertyTypeGroup", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"propertyTypeGroup\", intValue: nil) (\"propertyTypeGroup\").", underlyingError: nil))"**

What i tried here(referred some SO questions):

1. Given the api values as optional.
2. Given my array struct correctly in decoder line.

what else i need change to overcome this error?

my url-session line:

**let** decodedData = **try** JSONDecoder().decode([PreviousElement].**self**, from: data)

my struct:

```
struct PreviousElement: Codable {
    let id, email: String?
    let propertyTypeGroup: listingPropertyTypeGroup
    let propertyType: listingPropertyType
    let privacyType: String?
    let location: listingLocation
    let floorPlan, amenities: [PropertyTypeGroup]
    let photos: [listingPhoto]
    let photosPath, title: String?
    let description: [PropertyTypeGroup]
    let descriptionDetails, price: String?
    //let legal: [String]
    //let bookingInfo, bookedDates: [Any?]
    let isApproved: Bool?
    let firstName, lastName: String?
    let isRejected, isDeactivate, isListed: Bool?
    //let review, liked: [Any?]
    let createdAt, updatedAt: String?
    //let v: Int
}
```

Comment: Make the variables optional

Comment: @loremipsum tried, but still no change. Any other solution?

Comment: If after you make the variables optional it still doesn't work you are likely decoding the wrong thing, you have to examine the data you actually have vs what you think you have

Comment: Print your JSON received, check if it look good. It's hard to tell what's wrong, because tests show it should work (see quick sample: https://pastebin.com/6G5YBBuh) `let propertyTypeGroup: listingPropertyTypeGroup` should be `let propertyTypeGroup: listingPropertyTypeGroup?` according to the error, so print and show your JSON to have a reproducible example.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a full [mcve], specifically some sample JSON you are trying to decode that causes the error?